# Facebook app loads fine in firefox but keeps reloading in internet explorer 7,8,9

Tags: php, facebook, reloading

please check my app here- http://apps.facebook.com/indianresults

This app is loading and working fine in firefox but keeps reloading in Internet Explorer. I am using a simple code:

```
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=$permissions";
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
if(!$me)
{
           echo "<br>I am about to reload<br>";

           echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}
```

Would be grateful if someone can pin point the problem.

Comment: Are you sending the `P3P: CP=HONK` in the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending this header in the top off your document. Have helpt me with some similar IE specific problems when working with Facebook.

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

Comment: @thomaus I think you better add a new question to get some response, since there probably isn't anyone else than me who will see your comment! And add you code to it as well!

Comment: I've opened a brand new thread for my question : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7985012/eternal-reloading-page-with-internet-explorer